# Does "for when" make sense in this sentence?

Tags: sentence-meaning

Does "for when" make sense in this sentence?

> I don't want to bother you while you're off. So this message is for when you're in later.

Comment: It's a more precise way of saying "for later". I don't see anything wrong with it.

Answer (score 5):

Consider the many meanings of "for". The relevant one is:

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/for)
> for:
> on the occasion of or at the time of:
> *We're having a party for Jim's 60th birthday.
>
> I've booked a table at the restaurant for nine o'clock.*

In your example the occasion or the time is specified by
"when you're in later."
The message will be relevant or applicable to the time (later than now) when the recipient is in (at home, in the office, etc)

Answer (score 1):

Yep!
The use of for when in your sentence makes sense. So message is for which can be used at a specific time. For example:

> This is **for** the morning

So, in your sentence, you don't have a specific time, but it denotes a time. For when you're in, which is denotes the time when he's in.